# node.js + express 3 + socket.io = Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, pug

I'm new to learning node.js and seem to have run into an error that can't get to fix.

Its a very simple and beginners code so shouldn't need much explanation, more over it works fine on localhost, but breaks on production server.

**App.js**

```
var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path');

var app = express();

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8000);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.favicon());
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

app.get('/', routes.index);

var server = app.listen(8000);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
```

**And here's the dreaded error!**

```
http.js:644
    throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
          ^
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (http.js:644:11)
    at ServerResponse.res.setHeader (/home1/artalatc/public_html/cloud1/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/patch.js:59:22)
    at next (/home1/artalatc/public_html/cloud1/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:153:13)
    at Function.app.handle (/home1/artalatc/public_html/cloud1/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:198:3)
    at Server.app (/home1/artalatc/public_html/cloud1/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/connect.js:66:31)
    at Manager.handleRequest (/home1/artalatc/public_html/cloud1/node_modules/socket.io/lib/manager.js:564:28)
    at Server.<anonymous> (/home1/artalatc/public_html/cloud1/node_modules/socket.io/lib/manager.js:118:10)
    at Server.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:115:20)
    at HTTPParser.parser.onIncoming (http.js:1793:12)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete [as onHeadersComplete] (http.js:111:23)
```

Problem seems to be at `var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);` because commenting this like removes the error.

Comment: post your routes file.  the error is not from the index.jade file

Comment: Added. This is an auto generated file.

Comment: hmmm and so no errors when development but only in prod?

Comment: not sure if this has anything to do with it... but `var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');` wouldn't work in production.  maybe remove that from your index.jade file see if you still get the error.  that works fine in dev, because your server and client are both on localhost.  but not in prod.  the client and server are different.

Comment: although youre right and its a stupid mistake, but even fixing that doesnt solve the problem.

Comment: upon further investigation, commenting out `var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);` seems to rid the error.

Answer (score 7):

What version of Node are you using?

I had the same problem when I was using 0.9.x. I downgraded Node to 0.8.4 and the problem seems to have gone away.

My best guess is something in Node has changed that Socket.io doesnt agree with.

Comment: I did the same. Fixed the problem.

Comment: Is there any way of getting it to work with more recent versions of node?

Answer (score 4):

upgrade
   express - 3.1.0 and socket.io - 0.9.13

it's ok on nodejs0.10

Comment: This was the solution for me. Thanks!

Node v0.10.0, Express 3.1.0, and Socket.io 0.9.13.

Answer (score 2):

Which version of express are you using? Check out https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-2.x-to-3.x or try this:

```
var server = app.listen(8000);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

Comment: Already tried, problem is with `var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);` Check this thread as well: https://github.com/visionmedia/express/issues/1265

Answer (score 2):

i was having the same issue mate

if you are using express 3.0 you should try this:
http://codehenge.net/blog/2012/08/using-socket-io-with-express-3-x/

also check your version of node:

```
node --version
```

try using v0.8.9 or any other stable version

It helped me! And will help you

Answer (score 1):

For anyone bumping in to this issue you should be using:

```
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
server.listen(8000);
```

As express no longer returns a HTTP instance that socket.io requires. See the updated README.md file on https://github.com/learnboost/socket.io for the express 2 and 3 examples.

Answer (score 1):

This approach works in the current stable release 0.8.14:

```
var express = require('express')
  , app = express()
  , server = app.listen(8000)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue. Incompatible versions of express and socket.io were to blame. Upgraded them to express 3.2.4 and socket.io 0.9.14 and works like a charm.

Or you can downgrade your socket.io to a previous version, but you'll have to figure that one out.

Answer (score 0):

this error come because express internally use cache means for every second request data get from cache so it response back with 304 status code so use

```
app.disable('etag');
```

it tells the express each request fresh means with stautscode 200

Answer (score 0):

Change socket.io dependency to 0.9.15 in package.json, run `npm install` and it should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Run a npm list socket.io

Make sure it doesn't show invalid as below,

─ socket.io@0.9.10  invalid

npm ERR! invalid: socket.io@0.9.10 c:\Users....

If you get this error, npm install socket.io. 
Also make sure the same with other packages.