# Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using node version 0.10.3 and Express 3.1.1.

I'm trying to return a simple response, but I'm getting the following error:

```
http.js:692
    throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
          ^
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (http.js:692:11)
```

I've read a lot about it, and tried many solutions but I'm still getting that error.
I've used node-inspector and i'm getting the error after that line -

```
res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
```

**app.js:**

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path')
  , socketio = require('socket.io');

var app = express()
  , server = http.createServer(app)
  , io = socketio.listen(server);

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'hjs');
  app.use(express.favicon());
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

server.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});


io.configure('production', function(){
  io.enable('browser client etag');
  io.set('log level', 1);
});

io.configure('development', function(){
  io.set('log level', 1);
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('event', function(event) {
        socket.join(event);
    });
});

require('./routes')(app, io);
```

**routes/index.js:**

```
var utils = require('../utils')
  , config = require('../config')
  , io;

module.exports = function(app, socketio) {
  io = socketio;
  app.get('/', index);
};

var index = function(req, res){
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
};
```

**views/index.hjs:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
    <p>Welcome to {{ title }}</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "blabla",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "app.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "3.0.3",
    "hjs": "0.0.4",
    "cradle": "0.6.4",
    "twiliosig": "0.0.1",
    "socket.io": "0.9.11"
  },
  "subdomain": "blabla",
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.6.x"
  }
}
```

Any Clue?

Comment: The code you post doesn't seem to have issues (I tested it locally as well, works fine).

Comment: under the same version of node.js and express ?

Comment: Yes, same versions. I'm not seeing anything obvious in your code which could cause your issues.

Comment: Looks like some module sends the header before index function is called. Have you tried to comment out all unnecessary modules (most app.use calls, the io part and so on) to find the module that causes your problems?

Comment: I've tried to keep only : 
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'hjs'); 
in my app.use. still, it's the same problem when I navigate to localhost:3000..
The weird thing is that now it does load the CSS file (but still throwing that error)

Comment: Have you tried without `socket.io` as well?

Comment: @ohadinho Did you able to find the issue ? I am too stuck with the problem. I just updated the node to latest 0.10.4 and i am seeing this issue.

Comment: I just updated the socket.io module to 0.9.13, and express to 3.0.10, it worked. Reference in this link...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11801882/node-js-express-3-socket-io-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent

Comment: I had the same issue, and got it working again by reverting to these versions :  Node 0.8.22 // Express 3.0.1 // socket.io 0.9.11.  I'm going to try more recent versions in a VM until I find a combination that works.

Comment: @mani you should post and accept your own answer so the question is properly marked as answered.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be an error with your version of socket.io.

Use this:

```
"dependencies": {
  "express": "3.0.x",
  "hjs": "0.0.4",
  "cradle": "0.6.4",
  "twiliosig": "0.0.1",
  "socket.io": "0.9.x"
}
```

Tested with socket.io@0.9.16