# Node.js throws an error that says: Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I'm learning node.js. The code below is taken from a book which is supposed to be working. It throws `http.js:704 throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.')` if I access localhost:8080/stooges/chat

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var catchPhrases = ['Why I oughta...', 'Nyuk Nyuk Nyuk!', 'Poifect!', 'Spread out!',   
'Say a few syllables!', 'Soitenly!'];

app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.set('view options', { layout: true });
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

app.get('/stooges/chat', function(req, res, next) {
res.render('chat');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
var sendChat = function( title, text ) {
    socket.emit('chat', {
        title: title,
        contents: text
    });
};

setInterval(function() {
    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*catchPhrases.length)
    sendChat('Stooge', catchPhrases[randomIndex]);
}, 5000);

sendChat('Welcome to Stooge Chat', 'The Stooges are on the line');
socket.on('chat', function(data){
    sendChat('You', data.text);
});
});

app.get('/?', function(req, res){
res.render('index');
});

var port = 8080;
server.listen(port);
console.log('Listening on port ' + port);
```

Which line in the code above that triggers the error? And why?

**UPDATE:**
I commented out the line `var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);` and it seems to be the one that's causing the error.

**UPDATE:**
As requested by robertklep, here's the chat template:

```
extends layout

block scripts
script(type='text/javascript', src='/socket.io/socket.io.js')
script(type='text/javascript')
    var socket = io.connect('http://192.168.1.34:8080');
    socket.on('chat', function(data) {
        document.getElementById('chat').innerHTML =
        '<p><b>' + data.title + '</b>: ' + data.contents + '</p>';
    });
    var submitChat = function(form) {
        socket.emit('chat', {text: form.chat.value});
        return false;
    };

block content
div#chat

form(onsubmit='return submitChat(this);')
    input#chat(name='chat', type='text')
    input(type='submit', value='Send Chat')
```

Comment: Code looks fine and I can't reproduce the problem. Make sure your Node and module versions are (reasonably) up-to-date (I'm using Node 0.10.4, Express 3.2.0 and socket.io 0.9.14).

Comment: @robertklep: I'm using Node 0.10.5, Express 3.2.0 and socket.io 0.9.11. How come socket.io is older in my installation? I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 FYI.

Comment: 0.9.11 is probably the client version. BTW, could you show your template as well?

Comment: I don't know why it's not working for you, it works just fine for me. It looks like it's related to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11801882/node-js-express-3-socket-io-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent but there doesn't seem to be a clear solution apart from upgrading to latest versions (which you're already on) or going back to older versions of Node.

Comment: @robertklep: I answered my own question. Thansk for the help! Should I delete this entry? It seems like a stupid issue :-)

Comment: I don't think it's stupid, everyone can overlook things like this and it might help others in the future to resolve similar issues :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out I was using the wrong version of socket.io. I updated the dependency in pakcage.json from 0.9.10 to 0.9.14 and it worked. Thanks for the help!

Comment: History.md is showing the lastest version as 0.9.12 however updating to that from 0.9.10 solved the problem.